# Bold Text in GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms

In the following code-snippet I'm creating a `GroupBox`, where I would like the title to be **bold**.

```
Control containerControl;
containerControl = new GroupBox { Name = "" + viewGroupID, Text = viewName, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 20, Padding = new Padding( 2 ) };
```

The title is being set by the Text Property, but at the moment I have not been able to make it bold.

[image]

In the above picture, it's the "View Group A" that needs to be bold.

I have read, that this can be done by using a `label`, but is there any possible way to to achieve this just by creating a GroupBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by making a new font with `FontStyle` parameter added:

```
GroupBox gb = new GroupBox()
{
    Font = new Font( DefaultFont.FontFamily, DefaultFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold ),
    Text = "Text"
    //You can also use 'this.Font' instead of 'DefaultFont' to use the font of your form
};
```

Comment: Thank you, @EpicKip. That did the trick. Used your advise in the comment to use 'this.Font'.

Comment: @ClausMøllerJørgensen Glad it worked, i presume `DefaultFont` is the same font as the default for your form, but if you change the forms font it will change along :D